# Is there any way to encode mac to dos/windows using python

Tags: python

I have data file that is in mac format which only have CR/carriage line. What I need to do is to encode it to dos/windows format using python. So it would be a CR/LF format.

I saw one here but it says it's in perl. Can you give me a tip or a link on how to do so in python? Thank you

Comment: simple string replacement...see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: @Memming: much easier than that.

Comment: What research have you done yourself yet? I see several relevant questions here on Stack Overflow, for example. And what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Do you know how to open, read, and write text files in Python?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using 2.6 version of python. I'm sorry if I haven't included that.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes I know those things. I've see some related posts on the subject but they use other languages like perl.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to open the input file in 'U' or 'rU' mode to enable universal newlines translation, which will automatically convert all of the common newline forms (`'\r'`, `'\r\n'` or `'\n'`) to `'\n'`. Please see [the official Python docs for the open() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for further  details.

If you run your script on Windows, you can simply write the file lines back out to the destination file opened in text mode (with `'wt'`) and the newlines will be automatically converted to the native form, which on Windows is `'\r\n'`.

If you want the script to write Windows line endings even when run on non-Windows machines then you should open the destination file in binary mode and explicitly convert the `'\n'` line endings to `'\r\n'`.

If you need more explicit help on this problem, please make an attempt at writing the program yourself and edit the code into your question (properly formatted in a code block), clearly stating what problems you're having, and we'll be happy to help you fix it.